# Update columns of a row in trigger when values are 0

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers

I have a table in SQL Server 2008. In a webpage inserts these columns with 0

Columns:

```
id (identity)
enero (decimal)  --inserts 0 convert to null
febrero (decimal)--inserts 0 convert to null
marzo (decimal)  --inserts 0 convert to null
abril (decimal)  --inserts 0 convert to null
etc..


CREATE TRIGGER Pone
   ON  Rf_Egr_Meses
   AFTER   INSERT, UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN
    --  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --i don't know hoy compare if are 0 and what row 
  update Rf_Egr_Meses set ene=null , feb=null, mar=null where ()




END
GO
```

I can't change the webpage that inserts 0 for some reasons.

In a table I want create a trigger that converts the value from 0 to null (only if the value is 0)

Any ideas to create trigger?

Comment: i create a trigger but i don't know how update the inserted row and compare columns if are 0

Comment: thanks i Edited, Sorry but a only create the trigger i'm very novice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this - using the `NULLIF` function, which returns `NULL` if the expression is true:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgInsertNullIfZero
ON dbo.Rf_Egr_Meses
FOR INSERT
AS 
    UPDATE dbo.Rf_Egr_Meses
    SET 
        enero = NULLIF(i.enero, 0.0),
        febrero = NULLIF(i.febrero, 0.0),
        marzo = NULLIF(i.marzo, 0.0),
        abril = NULLIF(i.abril, 0.0)
            -- and so on, probably for all twelve months
    FROM 
        INSERTED i
    WHERE   
        dbo.YourTableNameHere.ID = i.ID
```

This will handle even multiple inserts that insert multiple rows at once.

You can try this by issuing this command:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Rf_Egr_Meses(enero, febrero, marzo, abril)
VALUES  (42.0, 0.0, 55.0, 0.0), (0.0, 17.0, 44.0, 49.0)
```

Now if you select your rows, you should see that for the first row inserted, you get two `NULL` (for `febrero` and `abril`) where `0.0` was supplied.